# Complex filter not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

I have a list that pages w/ a search radio on top of that list:

```
  <div class="btn-group" bs-buttons-radio ng-model="filter">
    <button type="button" value="all" class="btn span4">All</button>
    <button type="button" value="active" class="btn span4">Active</button>
    <button type="button" value="inactive" class="btn span4">Inactive</button>
  </div>

<div ng-repeat="u in (filteredUsers = (users | orderBy:'username' | offset: page*itemsPerPage | limitTo:itemsPerPage))" >
  <div>{{u.username}}</div>
</div>
```

my user object looks like this:

```
{
  username: 'username',
  active: true
}
```

When filtering on on active vs inactive I would do something like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="u in (filteredUsers = (users | filter:{active: filter} | orderBy:'username' | offset: page*itemsPerPage | limitTo:itemsPerPage))" >
  <div>{{u.username}}</div>
</div>
```

and that works just great.

Throwing 'all' into the mix complicates things a bit.

Is there a way that I can apply the filter in html such that 'all' would give me active and inactive users?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with @JLRishe's answer that for readability it's better to write a custom filter function, but for completeness-sake, it is possible, in fact, to write it as a filter expression.

Your `"all"` just means that your filter shouldn't apply. To make this work, your filter expression should return `undefined` for the case of `"all"` (thus invalidating the filter), and `{active: filter}` for other cases:

```
<div ng-repeat="u in users | filter: (filter != 'all' || undefined) && {active: filter}">
</div>
```

(I'm assuming here that `filter` can assume the values of `true | false | "all"`)

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/g2jejE8PG7hAYCEs2AxV?p=preview)

Comment: Still not quite working.  My "filter" values are defined in the radio html.  'all', 'active', 'inactive'.  I tried changing them to "true", "false", "all", but as they are strings I think that is screwing things up

Comment: How did it work before with `{active: filter}` without it being a boolean? In any case, you could do this: `filter: (filterActive != 'all' || undefined) && {active: filterActive == 'active'}"`

Comment: it didn't work.  That was the point of the question ;)  You will see in my first example I didn't use the 'filter' model as I was not sure how.  The 'value' attributes of each radio are defined in the html.

Comment: You said "and that works just great". Anyhow, does it work now? In the plunker link above I used booleans, but really what the filter expects is an object with the property to filter on and a value to match against. Since your user's property is a boolean, it should match against a boolean.

Comment: Yup you are exactly right {active: filterActive == 'active'}" is the right way if I am using 'active' and 'inactive' as the radio values (which is what I have in my question).  I thought you solution worked at first but realized you had {active: filter} which only worked if my radio values were true/false.  I was too quick with 'it worked' ;)  Regardless, thanks so much, I truly appreciate  it!

Answer (score 1):

How about a custom filter function?

```
$scope.filterActive = function (user) {
    switch ($scope.filter) {
        case 'all': return true;
        case 'active': return user.active;
        case 'inactive': return !user.active;
    }
}
```

Then you can use:

```
users | filter:filterActive ....
```

The object syntax you're using in your example only really makes sense when you're matching values against values. As New Dev's answer shows, it's possible to incorporate the "all" logic, but not very clean.

Comment: It is, in fact, possible to represent "all" - so, your answer is correct minus the last sentence.

Comment: @JLRishe thanks.  After looking at this I think you are correct.  Filter is applied in the directive but defined in controller and is probably much more clear.